# Does Absorbing have any powers in Lego Marvel?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

I mean, the question might answer itself but I was wondering if you got Absorbing Man and bought him, does he have any powers? Like can he fly or do as his name says?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/696964-lego-marvel-super-heroes/faqs/68458) FAQ on GameFAQs, he has no powers:

> Absorbing Man - Character Token in Manhattan
>
> Cost: 150,000
>
> [...]
>
> Powers:
>
> None

Comment: Thanks for the info man! Now i know not to switch to him. :P Haha!